# Saving enum from select in Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I am using the enums in Rails 4.1 to keep track of colors of wine.

**Wine.rb**

```
class Wine < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum color: [:red, :white, :sparkling]
end
```

In my view, I generate a select so the user can select a wine with a certain color

```
f.input :color, :as => :select, :collection => Wine.colors
```

This generates the following HTML:

```
<select id="wine_color" name="wine[color]">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="0">red</option>
  <option value="1">white</option>
  <option value="2">sparkling</option>
</select>
```

However, upon submitting the form, I receive an argument error stating `'1' is not a valid color`. I realize this is because `color` must equal `1` and not `"1"`.

Is there a way to force Rails to interpret the color as an integer rather than a string?

Comment: Where did the "input" method come from? Thanks

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Alright, so apparently, you shouldn't send the integer value of the enum to be saved. You should send the text value of the enum.

I changed the input to be the following:

```
f.input :color, :as => :select, :collection => Wine.colors.keys.to_a
```

Which generated the following HTML:

```
<select id="wine_color" name="wine[color]">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="white">white</option>
  <option value="sparkling">sparkling</option>
</select>
```

Values went from "0" to "red" and now we're all set.

---

If you're using a regular ol' rails text_field it's:

```
f.select :color, Wine.colors.keys.to_a
```

---

If you want to have clean human-readable attributes you can also do:

```
f.select :color, Wine.colors.keys.map { |w| [w.humanize, w] }
```

Comment: FWIW, I needed to make it `f.select :color, Wine.colors.to_a.map { |w| [w[0].humanize, w[0]] }` because `w` represented an array. Not sure why, but maybe this will help someone.

Comment: using `titleize` might be a better idea if you have two or more words

Comment: the `keys` method returns an array so the `to_a` is redundant. Alternatively the select helper method takes a 2D array for options so you can just use `to_a`.

Comment: What if an Invalid String is sent such as "ERROR_JUNK_Submission". Obviously there is no enum value such as this, and an exception is thrown. Where would we catch it?

Comment: The model Wine has a enum called color `enum color: [:red, :white, :sparkling]`so the correct sentence is `f.input :color, :as => :select, :collection => Wine.color.keys.to_a`

Answer (score 41):

No need converting the enum hash to array with `to_a`. This suffice:

```
f.select :color, Wine.colors.map { |key, value| [key.humanize, key] }
```

Answer (score 13):

I just put together an EnumHelper that I thought I'd share to help people who need more customised enum labels and locales for your enum selects.

```
module EnumHelper

  def options_for_enum(object, enum)
    options = enums_to_translated_options_array(object.class.name, enum.to_s)
    options_for_select(options, object.send(enum))
  end

  def enums_to_translated_options_array(klass, enum)
    klass.classify.safe_constantize.send(enum.pluralize).map {
        |key, value| [I18n.t("activerecord.enums.#{klass.underscore}.#{enum}.#{key}"), key]
    }
  end

end
```

In your locale:

```
 en:
   activerecord:
     enums:
      wine:
        color:
          red:   "Red Wine"
          white:  "White Wine"
```

In your views:

```
 <%= f.select(:color, options_for_enum(@wine, :color)) %>
```

Comment: The edit makes the translation keys more readable by finding enums belonging to MultipleWordClassName under the rather more typical multiple_word_class_name rather than multiplewordclassname

Comment: How about adding in a default for a graceful fallback: `[I18n.t("activerecord.enums.#{klass.underscore}.#{enum}.#{key}", default: key.humanize), key]`

Also, remove the last `humanize` as it may distort capitalization if its multiple words

Answer (score 13):

The accepted solution didn't work for me for the **human readable**, but I was able to get it to work like this:

```
<%= f.select(:color, Wine.colors.keys.map {|key| [key.humanize, key]}) %>
```

This was the cleanest, but I really needed to humanize my keys:

```
<%= f.select(:color, Wine.colors.keys) %>
```

Comment: rails 5 supports the cleanest way now

Comment: @V-SHY, what is this way, can you explain?

Comment: @ismailarilik, directly provide the keys as select option, <%= f.select(:color, Wine.colors.keys) %>

Answer (score 6):

If you use enum in Rails 4 then just call `Model.enums`:

```
f.select :color, Wine.colors.keys
```

To create HTML:

```
<select name="f[color]" id="f_color">
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="white">white</option>
    <option value="sparkling"> sparkling </option>
</select>
```

Or add method in controller:

```
def update_or_create
    change_enum_to_i
    ....
end

def change_enum_to_i
    params[:f]["color"] = params[:f]["color"].to_i
end
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to handle the i18n based on the enum keys you can use:

```
<%= f.select :color, Wine.colors.keys.map {|key| [t("wine.#{key}"), key]} %>
```

and in the tranlations you can set the colors:

```
wine:
 red: Red
 white: White
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is what worked for me, Rails 4+:

```
class Contract < ApplicationRecord

enum status: { active:  "active", 
               ended: "active", 
               on_hold: "on_hold", 
               terminated:  "terminated", 
               under_review:  "under_review" , 
               unknown: "unknown" 
              }


end
```

in `my _form.html.erb` , I have this:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.select :status, Contract.statuses.keys, {}%>
  </div>
```

test from Console after adding a record:

```
2.3.0 :001 > Contract.last.status
  Contract Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "contracts".* FROM "contracts" ORDER BY "contracts"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => "active"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution (my roles have underscores in them like "sales_rep"), and for some reason this was how I needed to get a blank option to work (with simpleform?):

In ApplicationHelper:

```
def enum_collection_for_select(attribute, include_blank = true)
  x = attribute.map { |r| [r[0].titleize, r[0]] }
  x.insert(0,['', '']) if include_blank == true
  x
end
```

Then in my form:

```
<%= f.input :role, collection: enum_collection_for_select(User.roles), selected: @user.role %>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me the following worked as well:

```rb
= f.input :color, collection: Wine.colors.keys.map{ |key| [key.humanize, key] }, include_blank: false
```