# When does create raise error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec-rails

I am testing with rspecs on model

```
 u = User.create(email: 'asd@we.com', password: 'asdasdasd', admin: true, firstname: 'qwe', lastname: 'wer', grade: 5, section: 'w', role: 'teacher')
       expect(u).to be_valid
```

but it raises an exception if role is set to a random value for example "principal" this happens because role is an enum with two possible values "student" and "teacher"

So in this case i cannot use expect(u).to be_valid. I have to catch the exception. The error it throws is

```
ArgumentError:
       'principal' is not a valid role
```

So i am wondering what other cases does .create throw an error instead of just populating the errors in model.errors. When should i catch errors? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you may want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780121/rails-test-validation-of-enum-fields).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a column in User model with type enum. The enum column in Rails is always raise an error if you're trying to set an invalid value.

The Rails core team [explaination](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13971):

> The current focus of AR enums is to map a set of states (labels) *to an
>   integer for performance reasons.* Currently assigning a wrong state is
>   considered an application level error and not a user input error.
>   **That's why you get an ArgumentError**.