# Rails - Is it hacky to manually list my form options as strings within the select_tag helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it hacky to manually list my form options as strings within the select_tag helper?

Also, I'm wondering--how do I actually use the selected value to update the database?

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :sex %><br />
    <%= select_tag(:sex_id, options_for_select(
      [
        ["Not known", 0], ["Male", 1], ["Female", 2], ["Not applicable", 3]
      ]
    )) %>
```

Comment: There's nothing "hacky" about it. On the contrary, it's the most unhacky code possible. :)

Comment: It was not a compliment, though :)

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686265/saving-enum-from-select-in-rails-4-1) outlines the process of using [`enum` in ActiveRecord (Rails 4.1+)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) for mapping to integers.

An attribute of type `integer` in the database can be declared in corresponding model (I assume `User`):

```
enum gender: [:not_known, :male, :female, :not_applicable]
```

In view, you may rely on the fact that the system wants corresponding strings, not integers:

```
<%= f.input :gender, as: :select, collection: User.genders.keys %>
```

Or map them yourself to generate what you want: "human-readable names" or even i18n keys:

```
<%= f.input :gender, as: :select,
      collection: User.genders.keys.map { |w| [w.humanize, w] } %>
<%= f.input :gender, as: :select,
      collection: User.genders.keys.map { |w| [(t ".w"), w] } %>
```

Comment: All right. I'm a novice here and am struggling to understand what you've written just a little. Firstly, where does your first code sample go? In the user model? In the sex model? And how does this relate to ActiveRecord? Is there a resource that I could read or watch that would break this down for me a bit more?

Comment: First code sample goes to whichever model has this attribute. As for the docs -- will add a link in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're hardcoding the options into the view will tend to make lookups difficult and localization/internationalization impossible.

There are many ways to do it better. Here are ones for you to consider.

Use a module that provides an enumeration, such as:

```
module Gender
  UNKNOWN = 0
  MALE = 1
  ...
```

Use a constant hash lookup, such as:

```
GENDER = {
  0 => "Not Known",
  1 => "Male",
  ...
```

Use a constant array where the index is the id, such as:

```
GENDER = [
 "Not Known",
 "Male",
  ...
```

Use a an array of structures, such as attribute key-value pairs:

```
GENDER = [
  {id: 0, label: "Not Known"},
  {id: 1, label: "Male"},
  ...
```

Use a database table, such as:

```
class Gender < ActiveRecord::Base
   # has fields for id and name
end
```

Use Rails 4.1 enum:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum gender: [ :unknown, :male, ... ]
  ...
```

Each of these options has strengths.

- In general I suggest using the database table approach for a typical web app, or typical API; the table approach has many advantages for easier scoping, searching, sorting, automatic display using admin tooling, etc.
- In general I suggest using the module approach if you need high speed, or have very tight storage constraints, or want to keep localizaiton/internationalization strings elsewhere such as a YAML file; the module approach stores the smallest amount of information necessary.

For sex and gender, heads up that these vary by region and userbase. For instance, some countries have a third gender, some contexts require a "Decline to answer", some groups distinguish between sex and gender, etc.