# facing issues in enum field in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

Hi I have generated a migration to add_column `rails g migration AddColumnToEmployees`

```
class AddColumnToEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :employees, :role, "enum('SUPER-ADMIN', 'HR','ADMIN','INVENTORY','EMPLOYEE')",  :default => 'EMPLOYEE'
  end
end
```

run `rake db:migrate`
Now I want to access role in my view for this I have written this:

```
<%=f.select :role, :collection => Employee.roles %>
```

But its not accessing it. It gives error 
`undefined method 'roles' for #<Class:0xc2acd88>`

Please guide how to solve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Employee.role`?  I don't think attributes are pluralized by Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your migration is fine. after your migration to access it in view like that

```
<%=f.select :role, :collection => Employee.roles.keys.to_a %>
```

and define enum field in model **employee.rb**

```
enum role: {
           super_admin: 1,
           hr: 2,
           admin: 3,
           inventory: 4,
           employee: 5
       }
```

convert in enum role of model into hash. and assign the value. and run it.i will try my best hope it will help you!!

Answer (score 2):

I was under the impression you represented the enum as an integer in the DB, so your migration should be:

```
class AddColumnToEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # Assuming Employee is the first value in your enum list
    add_column :employees, :role, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

and your select should be:

```
<%= f.select :role, :collection => Employee.roles.keys.to_a %>
```

See [Saving enum from select in Rails 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686265/saving-enum-from-select-in-rails-4-1)

Your model:

```
class Employee
  enum role: [:employee, :inventory, :admin, :hr, :superadmin]
end
```

Rails [does](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) automatically provide you with all potential values through a class method with the pluralized attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, I hope this will help you.

in **AddColumnToEmployees** migration file.

```
class AddColumnToEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :employees, :role, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

in **Employee** Model.

```
class Employee
  enum role: [ :super_admin, :hr, :admin, :inventory, :employee ]
end
```

and finally in **view** file.

```
<%= f.select :role, options_for_select(Employee.roles.collect { |e| [e[0].humanize, e[0]] }) %>
```