# Issue with Rails multi select options field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've set in my model('Bambino') a multi-select field to assign a value to the string attribute 'status'. Find the code below from my form partial:

```
 <%= f.select(:status, options_for_select([['segnalato','segnalato'],
['inserito','inserito'],['drop','drop'],['concluso','concluso']])) %>
```

When I want to edit my record the edit form does not give me back the previous stored value but sets automatically the default value to 'segnalato' (E.g.:if I create a new record setting the status to 'inserito' and after I want to edit the record I get the edit form with the default value of 'segnalato' while I am expecting to see in the field 'inserito').

In this way when you edit a record chances to make a data entry mistake are very high. Why so? Is there a way to retrieve the proper 'status' value that was assigned when the record was created? Thanks

Comment: Bambino gotta love it

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `@your_record.status` is equal to one of those values? Check it out before any further debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst `Andrey Deineko`'s answer is probably the one you want, there is a better way to achieve what you're doing: [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

```
#app/models/bambino.rb
class Bambino < ActiveRecord::Base
   enum status: ['segnalato', 'inserito', 'drop', 'concluso']
end
```

This will give you the ability to use the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686265/saving-enum-from-select-in-rails-4-1):

```
<%= f.select :color, Banbino.status.to_a.map { |w| [w.humanize, w] } %>
```

This will store a number for the `status`, whilst allowing you to define what each number means. It won't do anything about loading a pre-selected object (that's what `Andrey`'s answer will do), but will give you the ability to make your application & `select` more succinct.