# Rails simple_form check_boxes save multiple selections to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm trying to have a list to checkboxes with multiple selection.  I have this array in the model.

```
QOL = ["your health", 
    "your stress levels",
    "how safe you feel",        
    "your education",
    "your home"
]
```

I'm trying to do somthing like this in my simple_form form.

```
<%= f.input :qolselections, as: :check_boxes, :collection => Goal::QOL %>
```

How can I save the selections to the database and be able to retrieve them as the selected string values?

Comment: What library are you using for your forms, they look like: formtastic or simple_form?

Comment: @Leito im using simple_form (i missed the 'm' in the title)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a Constant, you should consider an enum:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum qol_selection: ["your health", "your stress levels", "how safe you feel", "your education", "your home"]
end
```

Then, your solution becomes similart to the one described in the following question *Saving enum from select in Rails 4.1* (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23686698/637094):

```
f.input :qol_selection, :as => :select, :collection => YourModel.qol_selections.keys.to_a
```

Comment: Thanks @Leito. What I am really interested in is being able to store multiple selections.  As in two values from the enum at the same time. Am I missing this from the post you linked?

Comment: Nope, I dropped the ball. That solution won't help. Sorry about that. Quick thought: You could serialize the response to convert and array into a single string?