# Form and contoller action to change Users Roles when roles is enum in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller

Suppose we have User ActiveRecord model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_roles, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And Users Roles ActiveRecord model.

```
class UsersRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: { guest: 0,
               os_employee: 1,
               os_contractor: 2,
               os_moderator: 3,
               os_administrator: 4,
               learner: 5,
               learner_representative: 6,
               teacher: 7,
               head_teacher: 8,
               system_administrator: 9,
               observer: 10  }
end
```

How to create a form and a corresponding controller action that will allow us to change a user roles? The form can be with a user form with nested roles attributes or stand alone form for users roles list.

Comment: You can make form to create new role. And for User form you can use available roles drop down with nested  attributes with multiple selection.

Comment: how about an action of corresponding controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear why you need a specific controller action for this.

You can add directly in the view, as one field of your form:

```
f.select :role, UsersRole.roles.keys.map { |r| [r.humanize, r] }
```

(check [Saving enum from select in Rails 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686265/saving-enum-from-select-in-rails-4-1) )

Comment: A controller action to handle the form submit

Comment: Would you please paste your code of current view and controller, so we may have a clear understanding of what you are trying to do? (I see this was from last september - is it still an issue ? ) What I mean is that your default controller action should handle this.

You will probably need to add role field to the permits

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested attributes using build
@user.roles.build

```
= f.fields_for :roles do |r|

   = r.select(:role, options_for_select(Role.pluck(:role)))
```

Comment: It does not work for two reasons, the Role not a ActiveRecord model and the User can has multiple roles.