# Rails select values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a select option in a form:

```
<%= f.select :role, options_for_select(User.roles.keys.to_a, params[:role]), {}, class: 'form-control form-control-lg roleSelect' %>
```

These roles are defined in my model:

```
enum role: {user: 0, profile_user: 1}
```

Now in my dropdown when the user choses it shows `user` and `profile_user` as drop down option.

Is there any way to show another value to represent these in a drop down?

For example:

In the drop down I would rather show "I am a teacher" which maps to `user`.

In the drop down I would rather show "I am here to study" which maps to `profile_user`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving enum from select in Rails 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686265/saving-enum-from-select-in-rails-4-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model add your narrative descriptions.

```
NARRATIVE_ROLES = {user: 'I am a teacher', profile_user: 'I am here to learn'}
```

Add a method to create the select_array

```
def self.roles_select
  User.roles.keys.map {|role| [NARRATIVE_ROLES[role], role]}
end
```

Then in the select you use

```
options_for_select(User.roles_select, params[:role])
```

Or (slightly simpler)

```
NARRATIVE_ROLES = {'I am a teacher' => :user, 'I am here to learn' => :profile_user}

options_for_select(User::NARRATIVE_ROLES, params[:role])
```