# Dropdown of UK personal titles on user registration form in Rails app and its implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise

I need to provide a dropdown to allow the user to select their personal title on user registration form (using Devise).

I need to have that list as a closed/pre-defined list rather than a field to be filled in by the user.

Do I need to create a separate model/DB table such as Title to keep a list of those UK personal titles (such as Mr, Mrs, etc) and then associate them with User model using many-to-many relationship and a corresponding intermediary table or is there some other option or better solution? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need just an static list, I would recommend to use an `enum` for this.

First add the needed field to your users table if you haven't done it yet. Run `rails g migration AddTitleToUsers title:integer`, and your migration should look like this:

```rb
class AddTitleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :title, :integer
  end
end
```

In your User model:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum title: [:mr, :mrs, :other]
end
```

And in your view, add this to display a dropdown with your enum values (assuming `f` is your User form):

```rb
<%= f.select :title, User.titles.keys.map{ |t| [t.humanize, t] } %>
```

Check [this enums tutorial](https://naturaily.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-enum) and this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23686698/4168348) of how to use select inputs with enums.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a constant array in your User model... add a field `title` to your User model

```
bundle exec rails g migration AddTitleToUser title:string
bundle exec rails db:migrate
```

modify your User class

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  TITLES = %w[Mr Mrs Mx Dr Lord] # add more as necessary
```

add a selector on your form

```
<%= f.select :title, options_for_select(User::TITLES, f.object.title) %>
```

Comment: This will not validate that the selected title is included in your `TITLES` list, so you can enter any value modifying HTML options on browser

Comment: Yes, but you can validate in the model. (shrug)